# Exception when trying to run the example from the Python.Net ReadMe on github

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll, python.net

On the github page for Python.Net (https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet) the following code is given an an example of typical use:

```
string exeDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        string envPythonHome = exeDir + @"Python";
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONHOME", envPythonHome, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", envPythonHome, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
        PythonEngine.PythonHome = envPythonHome;
using (Py.GIL())
{
   dynamic np = Py.Import("numpy");
   Console.WriteLine(np.cos(np.pi * 2));

   dynamic sin = np.sin;
   Console.WriteLine(sin(5));

   double c = np.cos(5) + sin(5);
   Console.WriteLine(c);

   dynamic a = np.array(new List<float> { 1, 2, 3 });
   Console.WriteLine(a.dtype);

   dynamic b = np.array(new List<float> { 6, 5, 4 });
   Console.WriteLine(b.dtype);

   Console.WriteLine(a * b);
   Console.ReadKey();
   }
```

After starting a project in VS 2015 (net45) I created a new C# file with this code the main method. I added `using Python.Runtime` and I used NuGet to install pythonnet_py27_dotnet. When running this I receive the following error {"Unable to load DLL 'python27': The specified module could not be found. `{"Unable to load DLL 'python27': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"}` with Stack trace

```
at Python.Runtime.Runtime.Py_IsInitialized()
at Python.Runtime.Runtime.Initialize()
at Python.Runtime.PythonEngine.Initialize(Boolean setSysArgv)
at Python.Runtime.PythonEngine.Initialize()
at Python.Runtime.Py.GIL()
at PythonNetIntegrationTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\users\<username>\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\PythonNetIntegrationTest\PythonNetIntegrationTest\Program.cs:line 15
at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Upon looking into the Python.Runtime in the Solution Explorer I see that the full path of this dll is `c:\users\username\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\PythonNetIntegrationTest\packages\pythonnet_py27_dotnet.2.3.0\lib\net40\x86\Python.Runtime.dll`.  It seems like VS knows exactly where this dll is. How can I instruct VS to find this dll?
Note, I cannot use IronPython, please do not suggest it. I am also only able to use Python 2.7 x86 due to constraints with other libraries with which I would like to interact.

Update: The code above has been edited with suggestions from issue #463 (https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/463). A different error occurs now: 
PInvokeStackImbalance occurred
Message: Managed Debugging Assistant 'PInvokeStackImbalance' has detected a problem in 'C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\PythonNetIntegrationTest\PythonNetIntegrationTest\bin\Debug\PythonNetIntegrationTest.vshost.exe'.
Additional information: A call to PInvoke function 'Python.Runtime!Python.Runtime.Runtime::Py_SetPythonHome' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.

Comment: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/wiki/Troubleshooting-on-Windows,-Linux,-and-OSX#common-errors

Comment: @denfromufa The wiki you linked to offers the following:' "Unable to load DLL pythonXX": CPython is not installed, or not registered in %PATH% and %PYTHONHOME% environment variables. Alternatively set PythonEngine.PythonHome property before initializing Python runtime.' I am using Canopy to install my Python so I tried PythonEngine.PythonHome = "C:\path\to\python.exe". This did not work. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please read again wiki, I updated with links. Your pythonhome should be set to directory, not python executable.

Comment: @denfromufa See edited question above.

Comment: you are probably on older Windows, so have a look at this issue: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/448

Comment: `pip install git+https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet`

Comment: @denfromufa Thank you so much! That did the trick. I'm sorry I didn't dig deeply enough into the issues.

Comment: No problem, I improved the wiki based on your question(s)

Answer (score 0):

I think `Python.Runtime` is not recognizing your python27.dll file which you will find inside the installation of python on your system. Just try the below code. I think it would resolve your issue.

```
string envPythonHome=@"C:\Users\YourLoggedInUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python27\python27.dll";

Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONNET_PYDLL", envPythonHome, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);        

using (Py.GIL())
{
   dynamic np = Py.Import("numpy");
   Console.WriteLine(np.cos(np.pi * 2));

   dynamic sin = np.sin;
   Console.WriteLine(sin(5));

   double c = np.cos(5) + sin(5);
   Console.WriteLine(c);

   dynamic a = np.array(new List<float> { 1, 2, 3 });
   Console.WriteLine(a.dtype);

   dynamic b = np.array(new List<float> { 6, 5, 4 });
   Console.WriteLine(b.dtype);

   Console.WriteLine(a * b);
   Console.ReadKey();
}
```